# How to generate reports on existing dump of logs using ELK?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

Using ELK stack, is it possible to generate reports on existing dump of logs?

For example:
I have some 2 GB of Apache access logs and I want to have the dashboard reports showing:

1. All requests, with status code 400
2. All requests, with pattern like "GET http://example.com/abc/.*"

Appreciate, any example links.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You should:

1. Install and setup the ELK stack.
2. Install filebeat, configure it to harvest your logs, and to forward the data to logstash.
3. In logstash, listen to filebeat input, use the grok to process/break up your data, and forward it to elastichsearch something like:

   ```
   input {
     beats {
       port => 5044
     }
   }

   filter {
           grok {
               match => { "message" => "%{COMMONAPACHELOG}" }
           }
   }

   output {
     elasticsearch {
       hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
       index => "filebeat-logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
     }
   }
   ```
4. In kibana, setup your indices, and query for data, e.g.

   ```
   response: 400

   verb: GET AND message: "http://example.com/abc/"
   ```